# Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException Calling unknown method: yii\web\Request::post()

Tags: php, yii2

I am new to yii2 and I have created a form, however it is showing the following error while loading the page:

**Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException**

**Calling unknown method: yii\web\Request::post()**

The code in studController

```
public function actionStudform()
    {
        $data = Stud::find()->asArray()->all();   

        $model = new Stud;
        if(($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) && $model->validate())
        {            
              echo "validate";
        }           
        else
        {
            return $this->render('studform',['model'=>$model,'data'=>$data]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: show your controller with all code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok

i also faced that problem and i had sorted out also

in yii2 you have to check that if form is posted or not ?
if form posted then you have to fetch data or print data

**try my code it working in my case with same error**

```
public function actionStudform()
    {
        $data = Stud::find()->asArray()->all();   

        $model = new Stud;
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        if($request->isPost)
        {
            if(($model->load($request->post)) && $model->validate())
            {                    
                print_r($request->post['Stud']);
            }
            return $this->render('studform',['model'=>$model,'data'=>$data]);
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->render('studform',['model'=>$model,'data'=>$data]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check namespace **use Yii** in your controller

**OR**

> I think this is again the composer dependency resolver doing unexpected things:
>
> - you require `yiisoft/yii2` in your composer.json but do not have the composer asset plugin installed.
> - then the dependency resolver does not find packages with vendor `bower-asset` so it looks for other versions of `yiisoft/yii2` that do not have conflict
> - The result is to install the beta version of yii2 to be installed

The correct solution as already mentioned is to install the [composer-asset-plugin](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin#npmbower-dependency-manager-for-composer):

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.*@dev"
```